# Fixing an error in a function that uses `replicate()` in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, sapply

I have an R function called `RR`. I'm wondering how to fix the following error:

`Error in rbinom(1, size = n, prob = p) : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or 
  earlier problems?`

```
 RR = function(n, p, n.sim){

fun <- function(n = n, p = p){
  x <- rbinom(1, size = n, prob = p)
res <- binom.test(x, n, p)[[4]]
c(Lower = res[1], Upper = res[2])
 }

sim <- t(replicate(n.sim, fun()))

mean(sim[,1] <= p & p<= sim[,2])

}
 # Example of use:
RR(n = 15, p = .5, n.sim = 5)
```

Comment: I would think there is some sort of lexical scoping issue with the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R throws this error message when you define defaults for a function that have the same name as the function parameters, and then call that function from within another function with the same parameter names. So `function(x = x)` is generally not a good idea. If you just change fun to 
`fun <- function(n2 = n, p2 = p)` your code runs without issues.

I do not completely understand myself why this happens, but it is easy to avoid.